# React.js and D3, adding arrows to forced directed graphs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I was closely following an approach to combining D3 with React given [here](http://bl.ocks.org/sxywu/61a4bd0cfc373cf08884).

By this pattern **structuring and rendering is done by React** and calculations are handled by d3.

```
var links = _.map(this.props.links, (link) => {
  return (
    <line className='link' key={link.key} strokeWidth={link.size}
      x1={link.source.x} x2={link.target.x} y1={link.source.y} y2={link.target.y} />
  );
});
```

This code segment is used to draw edges (links) between two nodes. I'm new to d3 so I was wondering how to add an arrow indicating *source->target relationship* between two nodes? That arrow should be next to a destination node.

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/fancellu/2c782394602a93921faff74e594d1bb1 look for the `marker` element

Comment: Since I'm rendering elements from React using jsx, could you tell me how to convert this code to jsx?

`svg.append('defs').append('marker')
        .attrs({'id':'arrowhead',
            'viewBox':'-0 -5 10 10',
            'refX':13,
            'refY':0,
            'orient':'auto',
            'markerWidth':13,
            'markerHeight':13,
            'xoverflow':'visible'})
        .append('svg:path')
        .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
        .attr('fill', '#999')
        .style('stroke','none');`

Comment: Just copy and paste the code as seen in the Developer Tools. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://bl.ocks.org/fancellu/2c782394602a93921faff74e594d1bb1 as an example

```
render() {
    // use React to draw all the nodes, d3 calculates the x and y
    var nodes = _.map(this.props.nodes, (node) => {
      var transform = 'translate(' + node.x + ',' + node.y + ')';
      return (
        <g className='node' key={node.key} transform={transform}>
          <circle r={node.size} />
          <text x={node.size + 5} dy='.35em'>{node.key}</text>
        </g>
      );
    });
    var links = _.map(this.props.links, (link) => {
      return (
        <line className='link' marker-end="url(#arrowhead)" key={link.key} strokeWidth={link.size}
          x1={link.source.x} x2={link.target.x} y1={link.source.y} y2={link.target.y} />
      );
    });

    return (
      <svg width={width} height={height}>
        <defs>
          <marker id="arrowhead" viewBox="-0 -5 10 10" refX="13" refY="0" orient="auto" markerWidth="13" markerHeight="13" xoverflow="visible">
            <path d="M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5" fill="#999" style="stroke: none;"></path>
          </marker>
        </defs>
        <g>
          {links}
          {nodes}
        </g>
      </svg>
    );
  }
```